# How check font lineHeight ( font.lineHeight) is deprecated or not using API (with out checking OS versions)

Tags: iphone

I want to check  `lineHeight` property of font is  is deprecated  or not using `respondsToSelector` . As `respondsToSelector` takes only method name .. how can i assign property to it ??

Answer (score 2):

First, check [the documentation for the property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006891-CH4-SW27). If it doesn't specify a custom getter, the method name is the same as the property name.

```
 if ([myFont respondsToSelector(lineHeight)]) { ...
```

See the section labeled "Accessor Method Names" in Apple's [Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2) document for more details on getter and setter names for declared properties.